# What guarantees SQL specification gives for UPDATE that both reads and writes some column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What guarantees SQL specifications gives for `UPDATE` statement where some column both being updated and read?

From my experiment I can see that when column used at right side of "=" sign, SQL uses old value, even though we update this very column in the same statement.

Consider the following T-SQL code.

```
create table test
(
    a int primary key,
    b int
)

insert into test
values (1,2)

update test
set a = b,
    b = 3

select *
from test

update test
set b = 4,
    a = b

select *
from test
```

The sample above yields:

```
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

Even though in the second update it seems to update "b" column before "a". Is it guaranteed that if I refer to some column I will get result unaffected by this `UPDATE` independent of the order of assignment in `SET` clause?

Comment: Yes this is guaranteed by the SQL standard (and everything else wouldn't make sense). You can even do `set a=b, b=a` and it will correctly swap values in the two columns.

Comment: This seems to be the relevant quote from the standard: "*The <update source> of each <set clause> is effectively evaluated for each row of T **before** any row of T is update*" where `<update source>` is the right hand side of the assignment

Answer (score 3):

The behavior that you observe is correct, it is standard, and it should even be intuitive.

The piece that your are missing are the ACID properties of databases and transactions.  The `update` does not take effect until the statement is executed.  Hence, any values that reference the row in the table come from the "before" view of the row.  The values that are set are in the "after" view of the row.

Comment: I'd try to rephrase sentence 2 in para 2. The effects of the `update` are visible after the *statement* is complete, to *the same session*, if it's using explicit or autocommit transactions, even before the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 3):

SQL tries to be a set-based language. For an `update`, this means that database systems try to act "as-if" all updates are applied in parallel, both to all columns within a row, and to all rows within the set. (Indeed, failures to implement this correctly can lead to the [Halloween Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween_Problem)).

Since all operations are "occurring in parallel", no assignment can see the result of any other assignment operation, and so they're all based on the original values of any columns.